# iFrame IE8 using jQuery ColorBox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe, colorbox

I am using the JQuery ColorBox with inline content that seems to work fine in most browsers, however when I use it in IE8 it loads fine the first-time then after that the iFrame part of the content doesn't show?

I have checked the source and the iframe is rendered in the html correctly. I am using asp.net 3.5 and c# for the server-side.

Server-Side code:

```
<script>

   jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery.fn.colorbox({ width: 376, inline: true, href: "#LightBox" });


        });
</script>

<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='LightBox' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>  
    <sc:Image runat="server" ID="imgBanner" Field="Banner" MaxWidth="346" />
    <sc:Text runat="server" ID="txtContent" Field="Content" />
    <iframe runat="server" id="iFrm" height="220px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" />
   <img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="loading" id="preload-img" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Client-Side:

```
    <div style='display:none'>
    <div id='LightBox' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>  

    <img src="~/media/Images/Premier/newsletters/ignite/header_4.ashx?mw=346" alt="Ignite" width="346" height="132" />
    <p><strong>Free e-newsletter from Premier</strong> </p>
<p>Hot topics impacting your life today...</p>
<p>You are invited to receive <strong>Ignite</strong>, the UK's leading Christian <br />e-publication, 
dealing with the hottest issues of our day: from abortion, to going 'green', to the debate over homosexuality.</p> 
<p>To receive your free weekly subscription to <strong>Ignite</strong> fill in your details below.</p>
    <iframe id="content_10_iFrm" height="220px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://email.premierchristianmedia.co.uk/premierradiolz//WebCapture.aspx?pID=334&amp;t=0"></iframe>
   <img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="loading" id="preload-img" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Until a fix is found, you can make IE8 emulate IE7 by adding this meta tag to the head section of your page

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. It appears to have loaded the iframe and 'thinks' the content is loaded but only shows as white, if I right click on the iframe and refresh it works???